# Using a for in loop inside a class results in a reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, module, for-in-loop

I am using a `for in` loop to iterate over keys in an object like so

```
var Obj = {
    foo: 'bar',
    num: '1234'
}

for(key in Obj){
    console.log(key)
}
```

Which outputs

```
foo
bar
```

However, when I put the exact same code inside a class method, I get

`ReferenceError: key is not defined`

The class I'm referring to is exported via it's own module. (Not sure if that's significant, because I can't find any info on this behavior online)

So why can't for in loops be used inside classes?

**Using Node V 8.6.0**

Comment: I think you were reading and old version of the question before I edited it...

Comment: **dooh** Edits question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use let or var

```
for(let key in Obj){
    console.log(key)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that was far too easy. Now, why did this work OUTSIDE of a class? Would you mind to point me to some documentation in your answer? I never used let when I was using a for..in loop outside of a class and it worked perfectly.

Comment: you should look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: @NativeCoder - You should always declare all of your variables with `var`, `let`, or `const`, even when you want them to be global.

Comment: Agreed. I have no idea why I though for in loops didn't require a variable declaration. But I don't want to delete the question because @Sajeetharan (and now yourself) deserve the reputation you have gained.